# Android - swipe tabs viewpager issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipe, fragmentmanager

I have an app that has 3 swipe tabs: "Map, "Events" and "Reviews". I've logged the data (as seen in my code wherever there is a log), and the following occurs.

I run the app and it opens on the 'Map' tab. The log however, shows

02-14 05:37:56.240: D/curent tab position(1787): 0
02-14 05:37:56.260: D/arg0(1787): 0
02-14 05:37:56.260: D/tab chosen(1787): MapFragment
02-14 05:37:56.260: D/arg0(1787): 1
02-14 05:37:56.260: D/tab chosen(1787): List_Of_EventsFragment

I click on the "Events" tab (the second tab on my actionbar) and the events fragment displays just fine. But the log shows the following, and also shows JSON processing which is NOT part of the "Events" fragment. it's coded in the "Reviews" fragment. So it still shows the List_Of_EventsFragment yet in the background its loading ReviewsListFragment.

02-14 05:38:37.890: D/arg0(1787): 2
02-14 05:38:37.890: D/tab chosen(1787): ReviewsListFragment
02-14 05:38:37.910: D/current page position(1787): 1
02-14 05:38:37.910: D/current tab position(1787): 1

As you can see, the 'current page position' and 'current tab position' are correct. They display 0,1,2 respectfully for each tab. The problem seems to lie in "arg0". I have tried changing my if statements to "if (arg0==1)" instead of "(if arg0==0)" and so forth. That didn't work as it produced a nullpointerException. It seems when the app loads, arg0 equals 0 and then 1 immediately after, even though the "Map" fragment is open and nothing has been clicked.

```
package com.example.eventmapapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FrontPage extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{

ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewpager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);

    viewpager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            Log.d("current page position", arg0 + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Map");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionbar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Events");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionbar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Reviews");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    actionbar.addTab(tab1);
    actionbar.addTab(tab2);
    actionbar.addTab(tab3);
}




@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}




@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.d("current tab position", tab.getPosition() + "");
}




@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Log.d("arg0", arg0 + "");
        if (arg0==0)                   //|| arg0==1
        {
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            Log.d("tab chosen", "MapFragment");
        } else
        if (arg0==1)
        {
            fragment = new List_Of_EventsFragment();
            Log.d("tab chosen", "List_Of_EventsFragment");
        } else
        if (arg0==2)
        {
            fragment = new ReviewsListFragment();
            Log.d("tab chosen", "ReviewsListFragment");
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.front_page, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty normal. When you load a tab it loads the tabs before and after it and destroy the other tabs and this is totally controlled by the ViewPager itself. This is called view preloading to show better smoothing while you are swiping between your views.

Comment: thank you. my emulator kept freezing up although it may be another issue with just my emulator. on the phone, I tested and it is working perfectly.

Comment: in my 3rd tab, it is using php and json. so when the 2nd tab is open, its already connecting to the internet and loading the json data. so is that normal? Thought something fishy might happen with that.

Comment: anyway it is working on the phone itself, and thank you for your comment :) I guess i'll mark this as done then :) thanks alot :)

Comment: This is normal and it's enhancing the UX so much, just imagine the opposite that the user waits at each tab until it loads.

Comment: Thanks.  Nowhere have I seen a reference that this is 'normal' behaviour.  I was enormously frustrated that my third fragment was loading when I selected the second fragment, and my third fragment was being destroyed when I selected the first fragment.  I've spent a long time on this - Appreciate your support.